# How to apply bevel modifier after cutting operation

Tags: bevel

Anyone knows how to apply the bevel modifier after the cutting operation? As the images below show, the cylinder without doing anything on it can be applied the bevel modifier, while the other cylinder which has been applied cut operation can't be applied bevel modifier, anyone know why and how to fix it? Thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

And I started a simple shape as the commenter moonboots said, and disabled the Clamp Overlap, but I still failed to bevel it after I did a cutting operation on it, I wonder if it can be beveled after the cutting operation.
[image]
[image]

Comment: As you've been asked before in your other questions, please add a link to the tutorial you're following and share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? The problem probably comes from the Geometry >Clamp Overlap option of the Bevel modifier that prevent the bevel to happen. If you want this bevel you need to modify the topology

Comment: https://www.blenderbros.com/products/hard-surface-modeling-jumpstart/categories/2150162633/posts/2157168362
Here is the tutorial link, and here is my blender file:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Xp7b5ZwZ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Xp7b5ZwZ/)

Comment: That's a commercial site so of course we can't see that tutorial without registering. I'll add the link to your Blend file into your question.

Comment: It is a paid course, we cannot simply watch it as I said on your other question. And as it seems, I'm quite sure that _Clamp Overlap_ is enabled in the _Geometry_ section of the _Bevel_ modifier. When you cut the cylinder and the result produces vertices/edges very close together, _Clamp Overlap_ keeps the bevel from going too far by beveling only as much as the minimum possible amount of all edges to avoid overlapping, no matter which _Amount_ you have set for the bevel.

Answer (score 2):

As you see, your topology here won't allow any correct bevel. You can disable the *Clamp Overlap* option (which will prevent the faces to overlap) but if you do it you'll have a very bad topology as result:

[image]

You'd better begin with a very simple shape that will allow you to easily bevel manually:

[image]

[image]

Edit: Your new topology is still not good, you have vertices close to each other which will create these overlapping faces, see if I merge them, it fixes the problem, so you should better copy the topology of my model (above):

[image]

Comment: A BTW ... The course OP is following is explicitly 'non sub-d'.. I don't know what its approach is, to this one

Comment: A paid-for course should certainly cover common problems that the OP is asking about here. Maybe there's a Q&A or FAQ section on the course where these issues are addressed?

Comment: @Robin Betts ah ok I can't watch the tuto without subscribing though

Comment: The course seems to be free 'in dollars' atm.. I guess Blender Bros  reward will in some way be related to the ( perhaps completely fair)  promotion of other products.

Comment: @moonboots I started a shape as you did, and I disabled Clamp Overlao, but I still failed to bevel it after I did a cutting operation on it, I don't know how to add an image here

Comment: maybe share your current file so that we can take a look?

Comment: I've edited my answer, your topology is still not good, also are you trying to be non-destructive as much as possible? Sometimes it's not possible and you need to bevel manually

Comment: @moonboots I've already share my file at the bottom of my post, please check it

Comment: Yes I saw, see my edit   ;)

Comment: @moonboots thanks for your edit, I realized there is no general way to do bevel, I need to handle it specifically

Comment: the Bevel modifier doesn't automatically work, sometimes you need to bevel manually or apply the Bevel modifier and correct the topology manually